# $.Ajax post array to Web Api 2 not working for me

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Data Model

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Web API 2 Controller

```
[Route("api/UpdateFoo")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateFoo(List<Foo> Foos)
{

}
```

JS

```
// here I need to create fooData which is list of foo


var fooData = [];
fooData.push({ Title: "title1" });
fooData.push({ Title: "title2" });

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/UpdateFoo",
    data: fooData
    }).done(function (result) {
        // good
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

What am I missing here? in fiddler it looks like I've sending fooData right however it is not recieved in Web Api Controller, I am being able to enter the the method with breakpoint however the value in an empty list

Answer (score 2):

I just spent a couple of hours yesterday on this. There is a known "quirk" in asp.net webApi when posting data via ajax [See Quirk Here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/177). And to summarize in your particular issue just add the following:

```
var fooData = [];
fooData.push({ Title: "title1" });
fooData.push({ Title: "title2" });

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/UpdateFoo",
    data: {'': fooData} //<-- the '' empty prefix name for the data
    }).done(function (result) {
        // good
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, donB! It works. By the way, do you know how to make it work in VB.net? I converted the code to VB, the list show the correct record#, but the content is empty.

Comment: @user1617676 sorry for the very late reply. I have not played with VB in a few. do you have some code to look at?

Answer (score 1):

Create another model to contain List

```
public class ListOfFoos
{
    public List<Foo> Foos {get; set;}

    public ListOfFoos()
    {
        Foos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

then your controller should look like this:

```
[Route("api/UpdateFoo")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateFoo(ListOfFoos listOfFoos)
{

}
```

now if you pass in JSON like this, you should be able to get the list in controller:

```
{
  "foos" : [
    { "Id": 1, "Title" : "f1" }, 
    { "Id": 2, "Title" : "f2" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/UpdateFoo",
    data: JSON.stringify(fooData),
    contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function (result) {
        // good
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```